# How to use latest SharePoint PnP Core Online in azure function v1

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sharepoint-online, csom

I just follow the instructions as below:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk

tried to add new version of `newtonsoft.json` and then installed the latest `SharePointPnPCoreOnline`.
It works well in my project and also I could do a unit test for my event-grid trigger locally.
But after I deploy to azure,an error will happen.It seems the function did not load the proper `DLL`

```
Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid.EventGridEvent.get_Data()'.
```

and executed this code when error

```
 [FunctionName("ProcessRequest")]
        [Obsolete]
        public static void Run([EventGridTrigger] string eventGridEvent, TraceWriter log)
        {
            EventGridEvent eventGridEventData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventGridEvent>(eventGridEvent);
            var siteCreationInfo = eventGridEventData.Data.ToObject<SiteRequest>();
}
```

very confused about the issue and made all my solutions but could not find the way.

Comment: The error complains about a missing EventGrid extension, not SharePoint. Have you added `using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid;` to your code? Does your project reference the [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid) package?

Comment: Yes ,I have this package in my project and the version is 1.0

Comment: Yeah,nothing to do with sharepoint.I want to install the latest package for it and it depends on the new version of `newtonsoft.json`.

Comment: The error you got has nothing to do with Json.NET. It complains about a missing EventGrid extension method. Either you forgot to add the correct `using` statement in your source file or you need to add the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid` package

Comment: I already have this package installed in my project,and in function class I also have the `using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid;`.What do you mean I should do?or should I upgrade this package?

Comment: Are you using obsolete package versions perhaps?   [EventGrid.Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventgrid.models.eventgridevent.data?view=azure-dotnet) is *not* defined in the `Extensions` package, in fact there's [no such class in the  Extensions Github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventgrid-extension/search?q=eventgridevent&type=Code).

Comment: In fact,If I did not add new version of newtonsoft.json and keep the version of 9.0.The same code works fine in my project.But currently I have to use new version so I have two versions of newtonsoft.json in myproject. Under this condition,this error happens.It seems that the object of EventGridEvent do have Data field but can not use.I do not know why this happens.

Comment: Not JSON.NET (although 9.0 is **ancient**) but *EventGrid*. The error complains about *EventGrid*, not Json.NET

Comment: regarding to `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid` version 1.0,the data is definded as `JObject`,and found that switch to `object`.Does it means in my project use the new version of object ?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/591)  I'm not sure is it same issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under this condition and if we have to use both of these libraries,it seems we could not to convert the object to eventgrid object directly.

```
EventGridEvent eventGridEventData = eventGridEvent.ToObject<EventGridEvent>();
```

because of the libraries conflict,we can not use this function directly.
We should get the key and value separately:

```
JObject eventGridData = JObject.Parse(eventGridEvent);
        var eventId = eventGridData["id"];
        var siteData = eventGridData["data"];
```

we should do data conversion in the simple way

Answer (score -1):

[The solution to overcoming this issue is by first manually installing a newer version of Newtonsoft.Json via NuGet.](https://www.eliostruyf.com/using-the-latest-sharepoint-pnp-core-online-dependency-in-your-azure-functions/)

Check the references.

[image]

My test project, it has warnings, but code runs successfully.

[image]

```
string webTitle = string.Empty;
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(@"{
                  'CPU': 'Intel',
                  'Drives': [
                    'DVD read/writer',
                    '500 gigabyte hard drive'
                  ]
                }");
            try
            {
                //Create the client context  
                using (var clientContext = authenticationManager.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(authArray[0], authArray[1], authArray[2]))
                {
                    var web = clientContext.Web;
                    clientContext.Load(web);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
                    webTitle = web.Title;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + ex.Message);
                webTitle = ex.Message;
            }

            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + webTitle+ jObject["CPU"]);
```

[image]

Comment: I just followed this manual but failed, and that error happened.

Comment: If I added the new version of newtonsoft.json and then I could install new version of `SharePointPnPCoreOnline`.But in my event grid trigger function I have to binding the variable to JOject, at this time the function will failed

Comment: Attached my test result.

Comment: The test doesn't show what it seems to be showing. JSON.NET doesn't contain extension methods related to Azure Functions. Upgrading it won't fix any error complaining about missing Azure Function extension methods. The error complains about an `EventGrids` error too, which has nothing to do with SharePoint either

Comment: This answer doesn't use any EventGrid methods, so it doesn't seem to answer the question at all

Comment: Yeah,it only happens the extensions in event grid